# Heroku: cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js app to Heroku, but I'm getting the error cannot find module 'express'. I've seen other questions here, but none of the answers worked for me.

My package.json file:

```
    "@zoomus/websdk": "^1.7.8",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "*",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "pg": "^7.18.2",
    "postgres-migrations": "^4.0.3",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "7.1.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

My logs:

```
2021-03-02T17:25:03.425345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-02T17:25:03.599923+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-02T17:26:08.319959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-02T17:26:12.230077+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674827+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674853+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674854+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674854+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674854+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674854+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674855+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674856+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674856+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674857+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674857+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674857+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:2:17)
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674857+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674858+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674858+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674858+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674859+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674859+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674860+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2021-03-02T17:26:15.674860+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Comment: If you remove the folder `node_modules` in your machine, and run `npm install`, does the project runs ok? Sometimes I catch such bugs by doing this.

Comment: @FirminoChangani I did that, and `npm install`  runs fine on my local machine. It's just on Heroku that there's the issue...